# With No Lock Tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions, locking, innodb

I'm running a stored procedure that involves more tables placed in joins.
My stored procedure do read operations on INNODB tables, writing to a temporary table created in this way

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmpDate
(
dates TIMESTAMP,
values INT,
ids INT
);
```

and finally UPDATE operations on a column of a table (INNODB) in which **surely** there are no conflicting operations because i do on it only INSERT operations (SELECT and UPDATE just in that StoredProcedure).

Every time I run it I get the following error message:

> Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

I immediately thought to be due to a hold to an **exclusive lock**.
Do you know a way to carry out NO LOCK table for a stored procedure or something that will allow me to execute my SP?

Comment: This error: "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" it's a problem with MySQL database. I've restarted it and my stored work fine. I don't have found answer how to no lock table for full sotre procedure....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error: `"Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction"` 
it's a problem with MySQL database. I've restarted it and my stored procedure work fine. I don't have found answer how to no lock table for full store procedure....

Answer (score 2):

You should not create TEMPORARY TABLES with InnoDB. [There was a past bug report on this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54044).

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmpDate;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpDate 
( 
   date s TIMESTAMP, 
    values INT, 
    ids INT 
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Tmp tables are best used as MyISAM since [**full table locks are imposed but non-blocking in nature**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5782/877).